# Using Friendly id to generate meaningful urls for similar names with different slug values- Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-url, friendly-id

I have already setup **[Friendly Id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)** following all the instructions from the [Home page](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).

In short,i have added the `module` and `slug` column in my **Place** model table.

**in my place.rb**

```
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders, :history]
```

I also ran `Place.find_each(&:save)`.

Now the value of `name` can be different,as there are many places with same names.So in the index action when i call the show action,using `id`,i get correct results but urls looks bad,However,when i call show action using `friendly_id`,url is bad here too with its uniq token like string attached and also i  always get wrong result.

for example.
For a record with `name` value as *burwood*,there can be multiple entries too.However,there are two problems:-

1. My urls should be like `www.mysite/sydney/burwood` instead of `www.mysite/sydney/21`,if i am using `id` and not `friendly_id`(which looks weird - *www.mysite/sydney/burwood-78894aa3-dea1-4915-b2f7-038182511005*),How to handle this. ??
2. If i **dont** use Id and use `friendly_id` as url parameter,For similar locations of value *burwood*,i am always get first record even if i am asking for other one.So in DB, `name` value of `burwood` having two records,my slug values are different - `burwood` and `burwood-78894aa3-dea1-4915-b2f7-038182511005`

**So if use id as url parameter,it works as id's are uniq and slugs are not considered but i want url to be more meaningful.**

**However,if i use friendly_id,url looks weird and also unique record is not picked up.**

Kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are many places with the same name, then friendly_id will append a guid to the end of the slug to make it unique.

You can try using friend_id candidates:

From the docs:

> A new "candidates" functionality which makes it easy to set up a list of alternate slugs that can be used to uniquely distinguish records, rather than appending a sequence. For example:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

  # Try building a slug based on the following fields in
  # increasing order of specificity.
  def slug_candidates
    [
      :name,
      [:name, :city],
      [:name, :street, :city],
      [:name, :street_number, :street, :city]
    ]
  end
end
```

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Alternatively you can roll your own slug by overriding `to_param` in the `Place` model and using a before_validation filter to set the slug.

```
before_validation :format_slug

def to_param
  slug
end

private

def format_slug
  self.slug = "#{name} #{id}".parameterize
  # You can define any rules for your slug here.
end
```

And if you want the params[:id] to read params[:slug] in the controller instead, then set `param: :slug` in your routes.

```
resources :places, param: :slug
```

And in your controllers:

```
Place.find_by(slug: params[:slug])
```

Comment: I can achieve this by using to_param but how can i make my urls pretty ?.I dont want to show my Id in the URLs...

Comment: You can add a `guid` column and generate a unique id with `SecureRandom.hex(4)` to create a random unique string/id. The length will be twice the value, so 8 chars long if we use the value of 4.

Comment: I can add an example if you would like.

Comment: Yes...sure...@codyeatworld